# How to access programmatically the list of resources in Plone 5 registry

Tags: plone, plone-5.x

I'm writing tests for some packages and I need to verify if some static resources are being registered correctly.

Before Plone 5 I can do that just by accessing the resource registries like this:

```py
self.portal.portal_javascripts.getResourceIds()
self.portal.portal_css.getResourceIds()
```

How can I accomplish that task in Plone 5?

Comment: perhaps so: [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.registry#accessing-and-manipulating-record-values), but i dont know how you do this in a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no easy way to accomplish this task and the proposed solution adds more than 10 lines of code, I would say that this test must just be skipped in Plone 5:

```py
IS_PLONE_5 = api.env.plone_version().startswith('5')

@unittest.skipIf(IS_PLONE_5, 'No easy way to test this under Plone 5')
def test_cssregistry(self):
    resource_ids = self.portal.portal_css.getResourceIds()
    self.assertIn(CSS, resource_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the answer to this lies in the [tests for resources in Products.CMFPlone](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/tests/testResourceRegistries.py).

Specifically, in the test cases in that file there are a number of tests that use the configuration registry to access registered bundles and resources like so:

```
from Products.CMFPlone.interfaces import IBundleRegistry
from Products.CMFPlone.interfaces import IResourceRegistry
from plone.registry.interfaces import IRegistry
from zope.component import getUtility

resources = getUtility(IRegistry).collectionOfInterface(
    IResourceRegistry, prefix="plone.resources"
)
bundles = getUtility(IRegistry).collectionOfInterface(
    IBundleRegistry, prefix="plone.bundles"
)
```

The return values of these calls are dict-like objects and they contain pointers to configuration registry entries for bundles or resources that have been registered using the `registry.xml` Generic Setup import step.

So, for example, if you have registered in your product a bundle using the following xml:

```
<records prefix="plone.bundles/my-product"
        interface='Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.IBundleRegistry'>
 <value key="resources">
  <element>my-resource</element>
 </value>
 <value key="enabled">True</value>
 <value key="jscompilation">++plone++static/my-compiled.js</value>
 <value key="csscompilation">++plone++static/my-compiled.css</value>
 <value key="last_compilation">2014-08-14 00:00:00</value>
</records>
```

then in the `bundles` returned by the resource registry above, you would be able to use the part of the "prefix" of your bundle following the slash ( `'my-product'`) to look up the registry record proxy for your bundle like so:

```
my_bundle = bundles['my-product']
```

That record will provide attribute access to the defined interface of a bundle (see [Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.resources.IBundleRegistry](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/interfaces/resources.py) for the details). So you should be able to check that it has the right values set for compiled js or css:

```
assert my_bundle.jscompilation == '++plone++static/my-compiled.js'
assert my_bundle.csscompilation == '++plone++static/my-compiled.css'
```

Records for registered resources will work the same way, a dict-like object with keys corresponding to the part of the "prefix" for your resource registration in `registry.xml` after the slash.  The records returned in that case will support [Products.CMFPlone.interfaces.resources.IResourceRegistry](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/interfaces/resources.py) instead. But you'll still be able to use attribute access to verify that the values you expect are properly registered.

If you have resources that are registered using the deprecated `portal_javascript` or `portal_css` tools (using the `jsregistry.xml` or `cssregistry.xml` Generic Setup import steps), the key to finding them is that Plone will now automatically include such resources in a special bundle called `plone-legacy`.  Since bundles have a `resources` attribute that provides a list of resources included in that bundle, you should be able to do something like this:

```
bundles = getUtility(IRegistry).collectionOfInterface(
    IBundleRegistry, prefix="plone.bundles"
)
legacy_bundle = bundles['plone-legacy']
assert "my-oldskool.js" in legacy_bundle.resources
```

Examples of this can also be found in the [tests for resources in Products.CMFPlone](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/tests/testResourceRegistries.py).  In particular, in the `TestResourceNodeImporter` test case.

Comment: thanks, my add-on register its resources using the deprecated registries; how can I find them there?

Comment: @hvelarde, I've edited my answer to include code I believe will work to accomplish what you seek.

Comment: still not working as expected, but closer: `legacy_bundle.resources` returns a list like this one: `['resource-plone-app-discussion-javascripts-comments', 'jquery-highlightsearchterms', 'resource-plone-app-event-event-css', 'resource-plone-app-event-event-js', 'resource-collective-lazysizes-ls-respimg-min-js', 'resource-collective-lazysizes-lazysizes-min-js']`

Comment: may be we need to use a regular expression to match both, `++resource++collective.lazysizes/lazysizes.min.js` and `resource-collective-lazysizes-lazysizes-min-js`.